# How can I convert XML metadata to PHP for SAML 2.0?

Tags: php, xml, yii2, saml-2.0, simplesamlphp

I try to get working test connection with Identity Provider as Service Provider using SAML 2.0. I am using Yii2 and SimpleSamlPhp library. To do this I need to fill in metadata for identity provider in file "simplesamlphp-sp/metadata/saml20-idp-remote.php". The problem is I got just XML file. I know that it is possible to convert XML metadata to PHP using built-in tool at http://saml.yourdomain.com/simplesaml/admin/metadata-converter.php 
but that tool just doesn't work. If I paste my XML file and press "Parse" page will be loading forever.

I have checked my XML file with validation tool (https://www.samltool.com/validate_xml.php) and it is valid.

Is there any online tool to convert XML metadata to PHP?

Here XML I use just in case:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?><md:EntityDescriptor xmlns:md="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:metadata" ID="aselect-s.entree.kennisnet.nl" entityID="aselect-s.entree.kennisnet.nl"><ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"><ds:SignedInfo><ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/><ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/><ds:Reference URI="#aselect-s.entree.kennisnet.nl"><ds:Transforms><ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"/><ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/></ds:Transforms><ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/><ds:DigestValue>wfZL1iUy/Gvct864xEiDf1+gtf8=</ds:DigestValue></ds:Reference></ds:SignedInfo><ds:SignatureValue>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</ds:SignatureValue><ds:KeyInfo><ds:X509Data><ds:X509Certificate>MIIF4TCCA8mgAwIBAgIEXXr4LzANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsFADCBoDELMAkGA1UEBhMCTkwxFTATBgNV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</ds:X509Certificate></ds:X509Data></ds:KeyInfo></ds:Signature><md:SPSSODescriptor AuthnRequestsSigned="true" WantAssertionsSigned="true" protocolSupportEnumeration="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol"><md:KeyDescriptor use="signing"><ds:KeyInfo xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"><ds:X509Data><ds:X509Certificate>MIIF4TCCA8mgAwIBAgIEXXr4LzANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsFADCBoDELMAkGA1UEBhMCTkwxFTATBgNV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</ds:X509Certificate></ds:X509Data></ds:KeyInfo></md:KeyDescriptor><md:ArtifactResolutionService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:SOAP" Location="https://aselect-s.entree.kennisnet.nl/openaselect/profiles/saml2/artifact" index="0"/><md:SingleLogoutService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:SOAP" Location="https://aselect-s.entree.kennisnet.nl/openaselect/profiles/saml2/sp/sso/logout"/><md:SingleLogoutService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Redirect" Location="https://aselect-s.entree.kennisnet.nl/openaselect/profiles/saml2/sp/sso/logout"/><md:SingleLogoutService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST" Location="https://aselect-s.entree.kennisnet.nl/openaselect/profiles/saml2/sp/sso/logout"/><md:SingleLogoutService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Artifact" Location="https://aselect-s.entree.kennisnet.nl/openaselect/profiles/saml2/sp/sso/logout"/><md:AssertionConsumerService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST" Location="https://aselect-s.entree.kennisnet.nl/openaselect/profiles/saml2/sp/sso/web" index="0" isDefault="true"/><md:AssertionConsumerService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Artifact" Location="https://aselect-s.entree.kennisnet.nl/openaselect/profiles/saml2/sp/sso/web" index="1" isDefault="false"/></md:SPSSODescriptor><md:IDPSSODescriptor WantAuthnRequestsSigned="true" protocolSupportEnumeration="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol"><md:KeyDescriptor use="signing"><ds:KeyInfo xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"><ds:X509Data><ds:X509Certificate>MIIF4TCCA8mgAwIBAgIEXXr4LzANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsFADCBoDELMAkGA1UEBhMCTkwxFTATBgNV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</ds:X509Certificate></ds:X509Data></ds:KeyInfo></md:KeyDescriptor><md:ArtifactResolutionService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:SOAP" Location="https://aselect-s.entree.kennisnet.nl/openaselect/profiles/saml2/artifact" index="0"/><md:NameIDFormat>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:unspecified</md:NameIDFormat><md:NameIDFormat>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:persistent</md:NameIDFormat><md:SingleSignOnService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Redirect" Location="https://aselect-s.entree.kennisnet.nl/openaselect/profiles/saml2/sso/web"/><md:SingleSignOnService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST" Location="https://aselect-s.entree.kennisnet.nl/openaselect/profiles/saml2/sso/web"/><md:SingleSignOnService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Artifact" Location="https://aselect-s.entree.kennisnet.nl/openaselect/profiles/saml2/sso/web"/></md:IDPSSODescriptor><md:Organization><md:OrganizationName xml:lang="en">skn</md:OrganizationName><md:OrganizationDisplayName xml:lang="en">Stichting Kennisnet</md:OrganizationDisplayName><md:OrganizationURL xml:lang="en">http://www.kennisnetfederatie.nl</md:OrganizationURL></md:Organization><md:ContactPerson contactType="administrative"><md:Company>Stichting Kennisnet</md:Company><md:EmailAddress>entree@kennisnet.nl</md:EmailAddress><md:TelephoneNumber>0800-KENNISNET (0800-536 647 638)</md:TelephoneNumber></md:ContactPerson></md:EntityDescriptor>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like there is an issue with your SSP installation. It converts fine with mine

`saml2-idp-remote`

```
$metadata['aselect-s.entree.kennisnet.nl'] = array (
  'entityid' => 'aselect-s.entree.kennisnet.nl',
  'description' => 
  array (
    'en' => 'skn',
  ),
  'OrganizationName' => 
  array (
    'en' => 'skn',
  ),
  'name' => 
  array (
    'en' => 'Stichting Kennisnet',
  ),
  'OrganizationDisplayName' => 
  array (
    'en' => 'Stichting Kennisnet',
  ),
  'url' => 
  array (
    'en' => 'http://www.kennisnetfederatie.nl',
  ),
  'OrganizationURL' => 
  array (
    'en' => 'http://www.kennisnetfederatie.nl',
  ),
  'contacts' => 
  array (
    0 => 
    array (
      'contactType' => 'administrative',
      'company' => 'Stichting Kennisnet',
      'emailAddress' => 
      array (
        0 => 'entree@kennisnet.nl',
      ),
      'telephoneNumber' => 
      array (
        0 => '0800-KENNISNET (0800-536 647 638)',
      ),
    ),
  ),
  'metadata-set' => 'saml20-idp-remote',
  'sign.authnrequest' => true,
  'SingleSignOnService' => 
  array (
    0 => 
    array (
      'Binding' => 'urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Redirect',
      'Location' => 'https://aselect-s.entree.kennisnet.nl/openaselect/profiles/saml2/sso/web',
    ),
    1 => 
    array (
      'Binding' => 'urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST',
      'Location' => 'https://aselect-s.entree.kennisnet.nl/openaselect/profiles/saml2/sso/web',
    ),
    2 => 
    array (
      'Binding' => 'urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Artifact',
      'Location' => 'https://aselect-s.entree.kennisnet.nl/openaselect/profiles/saml2/sso/web',
    ),
  ),
  'SingleLogoutService' => 
  array (
  ),
  'ArtifactResolutionService' => 
  array (
    0 => 
    array (
      'Binding' => 'urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:SOAP',
      'Location' => 'https://aselect-s.entree.kennisnet.nl/openaselect/profiles/saml2/artifact',
      'index' => 0,
    ),
  ),
  'NameIDFormats' => 
  array (
    0 => 'urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:unspecified',
    1 => 'urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:persistent',
  ),
  'keys' => 
  array (
    0 => 
    array (
      'encryption' => false,
      'signing' => true,
      'type' => 'X509Certificate',
      'X509Certificate' => 'MIIF4TCCA8mgAwIBAgIEXXr4LzANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsFADCBoDELMAkGA1UEBhMCTkwxFTATBgNV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',
    ),
  ),
);
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked this time. Now I got other problems not related to this question. But how can I find out what is wrong with my configuration?

Comment: @OlegAntoniuk There is a users mailing list that people use for questions: https://simplesamlphp.org/lists

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will ask my questions there.